# Ubuntu + Netbeans - Zend framework fatal error due to Include path

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I'm experiencing a problem with my 'include' path on my fresh install of Zend framework. i'm running Ubuntu and using Netbeans. I installed Zend via the terminal and I have copied the appropriate files to my new project.

I am currently getting this while attempting to access localhost/demoZend/public

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mastered/public_html/demoZend/public/index.php on line 18

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='/home/mastered/public_html/demoZend/library:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /home/mastered/public_html/demoZend/public/index.php on line 18
```

I have copied the 'Zend' folder with the framework into my project/library folder so the folder structure is /demoZend/library/Zend/

I have also changed the 'include' path in my php.ini from the advice of a tutorial. however this is where I have things confused.

The path reads:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/"
```

in my apache2/php.ini *aswell as* my /etc/php5/cli/php.ini file.

My index.php file in my project reads as thus:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

I haven't changed that as the file paths seem ok. 
I should also point out I have my web documents stored in my '~/public_html' directory, I have checked the permissions on my 'demoZend/library' folder and they have all restrictions *off*.

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not `/home/mastered/public_html/demoZend/library/Zend/Application.php` exists?

Comment: inside the /Zend/ folder are plenty of folders but no Application.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're following a tutorial for Zend Framework 1, but you've downloaded Zend Framework 2. There is no `Zend/Application.php` in ZF2, so that's why PHP isn't finding the file.

You can either head back to the ZF downloads page and grab the latest release of ZF1 (currently 1.12.3), or find a ZF2 tutorial and learn ZF2 instead. If you're just getting started with ZF, I'd go with the latter option.